# How to set image path in linux command line?

Tags: linux

How to set image path in linux command line ?

I tried to use this image path

```
/home/testuser/public_html/img/test.jpg
```

With this code in linux command line (`putty`)

```
jpegoptim --max=75 /home/testuser/public_html/img/test.jpg
```

But not work, How can i do that ?

Comment: when writing a Q like this, we have no idea what you mean by `But not work"`. Please update your Q to include evidence. Error messages are best, else `ls -ld /home/testuser/public_html/img/*` may help. Good luck.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file exists and that it is readable. The directory should be writable too.

Try

```
sudo chmod 666 /home/testuser/public_html/img/test.jpg
```

and

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/testuser/public_html/img
```

Comment: but why i can not use shell_exec like this code 

`<?php
$command = 'jpegoptim --max=75 /home/mnpnln25/public_html/img/test.jpg';
echo shell_exec($command);
?>`