# How do you use PHP on the command line to run jpegoptim?

Tags: php, shell, putty, shell-exec

In the `putty` command line I use this code:

```
jpegoptim --max=75 /home/testuser/public_html/img/test.jpg
```

It works well. Then I tried to use this code using the PHP command line interface, like this.

```
<?php
$command = 'jpegoptim --max=75 /home/testuser/public_html/img/test.jpg';
shell_exec($command);
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: "not work" did it cause the server to explode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Variables to shell\_exec()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932113/passing-variables-to-shell-exec)

Comment: you've slightly improved the quality of this Q. Can  you please delete your previous Q on the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374089/how-to-set-image-path-in-linux-command-line , Thanks and Good Luck.